# Как сделать исключение класса в парсере, чтобы парсер исключал определенный класс

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Мне нужно, чтобы парсер не собирал данные из класса `<ul class="b-catalog__subcats is-inner">`, а всю остальную информацию собирал, как мне это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

HTML-код откуда парсер берет данные:

```
<div class="wrapper-short">
<h4>Особенности:</h4>
<ul>
<li>Многоплатная схема</li>
<li>Подключение 220 В</li>
<li>Горелка 26 серии в комплекте</li>
<li>ПВ 60% при токе 200 Ампер</li>
<li>Полноценная функция ручной дуговой сварки MMA</li>
<li>Автоматическая защита от перегрева</li>
<li>Регулировка продувки газом после сварки</li>
<li>Полная комплектация + ЗИП</li>
<li>Прочная коробка для транспортировки</li>
<li>Гарантия 2 года</li>
</ul>
<h4>Комплектация:</h4>
<ul>
<li>Инверторный аппарат аргонодуговой сварки - 1 шт.</li>
<li>Клемма заземления с кабелем - 1 шт. </li>
<li>Аргонодуговая горелка 26 серии  - 1 шт.</li>
<li>Паспорт оборудования - 1 шт.</li>
</ul>
<ul class="b-catalog__subcats is-inner">
<li>
<a href="https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/svarochnye-invertory/220v-2">220 вольт</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-argonodugovoy-svarki-tig/tig-200">TIG 200</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-argonodugovoy-svarki-tig/220v">220 вольт</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/svarochnye-invertory/master-2">Мастер</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-argonodugovoy-svarki-tig/postoyannyj-tok">DC</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-argonodugovoy-svarki-tig/master">Мастер</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/svarochnye-invertory/200-amper">200 ампер</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Вот сам парсер:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/product/ptk-master-tig-200'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_html_vivod(html):
    svarka = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-product-tab__item is-active')
    for item in items:  
        svarka.append({
            "text": item.find('div', class_='wrapper-short')
            })
    return svarka

html = get_html(URL)
print(get_html_vivod(html.text))
```

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). А так ответ пока один -- исключайте данные, что вам не нужны, используя, например, `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в расчет брать только класс `wrapper-short` (на странице есть другие данные), то получить данные можно следующим образом.

Класс `b-catalog__subcats is-inner` избегается за счет поиска тега `ul` с пустым значением класса `items.find_all('ul', class_='')`. В блоке `wrapper-short` находится три `ul`, два из которых без класса.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import os

def get_html(url, params=None):
    return requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)

def parse_html(html):
    items = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('div', class_='wrapper-short')

    desctiption = [p.text for p in items.find_all('p')]  
    features, equipment = items.find_all('ul', class_='')

    return desctiption, features.text, equipment.text

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/product/profi-tig-315-p-acdc'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

html = get_html(URL)
data = parse_html(html.text)

print(data[0]) # desctiption
print(data[1]) # features
print(data[2]) # equipment
```